# WPF Custom Transparent Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like create a button with text and image inside in, but this button should be transparent without loose behavior as cursors hand on mouse over and so on..
Also, it doesn't change its background color on mouse over. It's Always should appear transparent showing only my text and my image.

Is it possibile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a very simple `ControlTemplate` will produce the desired output :

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TransparentButton" TargetType="Button">
    <ContentPresenter Cursor={TemplateBinding Cursor}/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then simply apply if to the `Template`property of your button.

---

Just add a `{TemplateBinding Property}` for the any properties you want to inherit. You should have a look at the default ControlTemplates on MSDN for your specific target (it may vary if targeting WP8, Silverlight or desktop)

Comment: Id doesn't work because when I on mouse over my cursors doesn't change as expected (it should be "hand").